# Associated fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, schemes, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $X$ a quasiprojective $k$ scheme, $G$ a smooth linear algebraic group. We consider $f:P \to X$ to be a principal $G$-bundle (here I'm assuming $f$ to be locally trivial in the etale topology). Given now another quasi projective $k$ scheme $F$ with a $G$ action, we consider the (right) $G$-action on $P \times_k F$ defined by: $$g \cdot (p,f)=(pg,g^{-1}f) .$$

I've seen claimed that the quotient $P \times_k F/G$ always exists (with no condition on $G$), but I was not able to prove that. In particular, I was not able to specialize the standard topological proof to the algebrogeometric context, given that we have just etale local triviality.

Comment: Do you know the fact that quasi-projective varieties satisfy effective etale descent? Can you prove the quotient exists when $P$ is the trivial $G$-torsor?

Comment: I think I'm able to prove this for the trivial $G$-torsor $G \times_k X$: in this case, using the action map $G \times_k F \to F$ one should be able to prove $ G \times_k X \times_k F/G \cong X \times_k F$. However, I've got to admit I don't know anything about etale descent

Comment: I mean, this sounds annoying to do without that assumption. The descent just says that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf which is etale locally representable by a quasi-projective scheme, then it’s representable by a quasi-projective scheme. The point here is that etale locally $P$ is trivial, so you get your result easily from what you said, then you can descend back down to existence by what I just said.

Comment: I'm sorry what do youn mean by etale locally? Where could I find a precise statement for etale descent?